# How do I introduce a constraint in django table where values from 2 columns will be unique in a table and other rows can have duplicate pairs?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework

How do I introduce a constraint in **Django** table where 2 values of a column will be unique in a table and other rows can have duplicate pairs?

like

```
a True
a False
a False
a False
```

```
a True
b True
a False
a False
a False
b False
b False
```

but not

```
a True
a True
a False
a False
a False
```

```
b True
b True
a False
a False
a False
b False
b False
```

So, I want only one value of left column to be True.

To think of it practically, consider the first column to be name and the second column to be default.

I want only one value in the name column to have `default = True`, but it can have multiple instances of `default = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if we can actually do that with the model by adding constraints. But I think I came up with a solution.

I do not know what you're using Django for, but if you're building a web application and you're using a form, call an API on form submit and POST the data to the back-end. Now, this data should not directly be stored in the database. First, run through a validating function which checks if that particular data would violate your rule. If yes, send an error as the response. If not, save the data.

Comment: Can you give me a validate function example please? Yes, I am using it for a web application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actually mean by "one value with default=True and multiple with default=False" a column can *only have 1 default*. But I think you just confusing default with value. That you can have. What you are looking for a a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-partial.html). What actual table definition I will just create an example table.  see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7289b4d80bc2394d21742f9a1a9eb9cd)

```
create table some_table( id integer generated always as identity 
                                    primary key
                       , col_name   text
                       , is_active  boolean default true
                       ); 
-- Now create the partial unique index
create unique index some_table_1_active 
       on some_table (col_name)
where is_active;
```

Sorry, I am not sure how you need to write this in your obsurfication layer (Django). I guess if necessary you could create the index with raw SQL (?).